# php - issue with date-format

Tags: php, date

I am struggeling with some basic date-formatting and echo the right number for "Days Left". This is the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$dateNow = date('d/m/Y', time());
$dateStart = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('01/08/2014'));
$dateFinished = date('d-m-Y', $dateStart + strtotime("+62 days"));
$daysLeft = intval($dateFinished-$dateNow);

echo($dateNow. "<br>");
echo($dateStart. "<br>");
echo($daysLeft. "<br>");
```

**This is the echo:**
07/07/2014
01/08/2014
-6

It seems like dateStart is interped as a wrong format. I have tried with both **-** and **/**, but nothing better.

What have i done wrong? Just the math or is it the logic?

Comment: `var_dump($dateStart + strtotime("+62 days"));` --- never assume, always check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use OOP (Object-oriented) in this case. It is easier to write and easier to understand.

Just made a simple and short script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$dateNow = new DateTime('now');
$dateStart = new DateTime('2014-08-01');
$dateFinished = new DateTime($dateStart->format('Y-m-d'));
$dateFinished->add(new DateInterval('P62D'));
$daysLeft = $dateFinished->diff($dateNow);

echo($dateNow->format('d/m/Y'). "<br>");
echo($dateStart->format('d/m/Y'). "<br>");
echo($daysLeft->format('%d'). "<br>");
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't this modify datestart to? $dateStart->add(new DateInterval('P62D') @Yannici

Comment: Of course. Thank you for the hint :P I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$dateStart` is a string. You need to do:

```
$dateStart = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('01/08/2014'));
$dateFinished = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+62 days", strtotime('01/08/2014')));
```

For more sophisticated date calculations consider `DateTime()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP is 5.3+, than you can use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and calculate difference between dates:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2007-03-24");
$date2 = new DateTime("2009-06-26");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```

OR

```
echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";
```